# Speech-to-Text API v2 Issue with Python (Permission Denied)

Tags: google-cloud-iam

*Work in Google Shell only with path set command "exports... ". Don't work in shell with "PATH" in code and on my main platform Python Local*

I'm facing a perplexing issue transitioning from PHP to Python for a project involving Google's Speech-to-Text API, specifically the newer v2 version. I've previously implemented a successful project in PHP using version 1 of the API. However, while migrating to Python for better alignment with the v2 API and Google's documentation, I've hit a snag with permissions.

-The Core Issue:

In PHP, everything worked seamlessly, but in Python, I'm encountering a PermissionDenied error related to the speech.recognizers.recognize permission. This is confusing because the same project and service account worked fine in PHP.

-Code Snippet (Python):

```
import os
from google.cloud.speech_v2 import SpeechClient
from google.cloud.speech_v2.types import cloud_speech

credential_path = "C:\\Users\\Joffrey-PTMG\\Desktop\\U23\\OFC-SUBM2.0\\authgooglejson\\hidekey.json"
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credential_path

def transcribe_file_v2(
    project_id: str,
    audio_file: str,
) -> cloud_speech.RecognizeResponse:
    
    print(project_id)
    # Instantiates a client
    client = SpeechClient()

    # Reads a file as bytes
    with open(audio_file, "rb") as f:
        content = f.read()

    config = cloud_speech.RecognitionConfig(
        auto_decoding_config=cloud_speech.AutoDetectDecodingConfig(),
        language_codes=["fr-FR"],
        model="long",
    )

    request = cloud_speech.RecognizeRequest(
        recognizer=f"projects/{project_id}/locations/global/recognizers/_",
        config=config,
        content=content,
    )

    # Transcribes the audio into text
    response = client.recognize(request=request)

    for result in response.results:
        print(f"Transcript: {result.alternatives[0].transcript}")

    return response

project_idvar = 'eighth-server-267708'
audio_filevar = 'testtt.mp3'

transcribe_file_v2(project_idvar, audio_filevar)
```

-Google Cloud Shell Error:

```
Welcome to Cloud Shell! Type "help" to get started.
Your Cloud Platform project in this session is set to eighth-server-267708.
Use “gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]” to change to a different project.
vedlem_mail@cloudshell:~ (eighth-server-267708)$ python projshell11.py
eighth-server-267708
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 75, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 1161, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 1004, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)  # pytype: disable=not-instantiable
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
        details = "Permission 'speech.recognizers.recognize' denied on resource (or it may not exist)."
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:74.125.140.95:443 {grpc_message:"Permission \'speech.recognizers.recognize\' denied on resource (or it may not exist).", grpc_status:7, created_time:"2023-12-04T07:29:41.163760308+00:00"}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vedlem_mail/projshell11.py", line 44, in <module>
    transcribe_file_v2(project_idvar, audio_filevar)
  File "/home/vedlem_mail/projshell11.py", line 34, in transcribe_file_v2
    response = client.recognize(request=request)
  File "/home/vedlem_mail/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/speech_v2/services/speech/client.py", line 1482, in recognize
    response = rpc(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 131, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 77, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Permission 'speech.recognizers.recognize' denied on resource (or it may not exist). [reason: "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED"
domain: "iam.googleapis.com"
metadata {
  key: "permission"
  value: "speech.recognizers.recognize"
}
]
vedlem_mail@cloudshell:~ (eighth-server-267708)$
```

-Local Python Error:

```
C:\Users\Joffrey-PTMG\Desktop\U23\OFC-SUBM2.0>python proj1.py
eighth-server-267708
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pythonCore\Lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 75, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\pythonCore\Lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 1161, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\pythonCore\Lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 1004, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)  # pytype: disable=not-instantiable
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
        details = "Permission 'speech.recognizers.recognize' denied on resource (or it may not exist)."
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv6:%5B2a00:1450:4007:81a::200a%5D:443 {grpc_message:"Permission \'speech.recognizers.recognize\' denied on resource (or it may not exist).", grpc_status:7, created_time:"2023-12-04T07:30:15.8905988+00:00"}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joffrey-PTMG\Desktop\U23\OFC-SUBM2.0\proj1.py", line 44, in <module>
    transcribe_file_v2(project_idvar, audio_filevar)
  File "C:\Users\Joffrey-PTMG\Desktop\U23\OFC-SUBM2.0\proj1.py", line 34, in transcribe_file_v2
    response = client.recognize(request=request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\pythonCore\Lib\site-packages\google\cloud\speech_v2\services\speech\client.py", line 1482, in recognize
    response = rpc(
               ^^^^
  File "C:\pythonCore\Lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 131, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\pythonCore\Lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 77, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Permission 'speech.recognizers.recognize' denied on resource (or it may not exist). [reason: "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED"
domain: "iam.googleapis.com"
metadata {
  key: "permission"
  value: "speech.recognizers.recognize"
}
]
```

I've been trying to run my Python script directly through the Google Cloud Shell. Interestingly, the environment variable PATH didn't work as seamlessly as it did for my PHP project. So, I included the following lines in my Python script to set the credentials path:

```
credential_path = "C:\\Users\\Joffrey-PTMG\\Desktop\\U23\\OFC-SUBM2.0\\authgooglejson\\hidekey.json"
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credential_path
```

This was intended to make it work, but even after removing these lines and trying to set the environment variable through the Cloud Shell using:

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/home/vedlem_mail/jsonss/hidekey.json'`

I encountered the same error. So it seemed to me that these lines were not the root of the problem but we don't know why now..

the version without the lines to define the path but with the exports line executed this works only on the google shell (probably thanks to a restart of the shell)

My goal is to simply use Speech to Text on an .mp3 file. I'm trying to overcome what appears to be a false error since I am designated as "Owner" in the role settings. This setup worked perfectly in PHP, so I don't understand why it doesn't work in Python.

Help me  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've come across the same issue and found that A service agent is required for speech v2.  https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-agents and search for speech then create it using GCP commands.

```
gcloud beta services identity create --service=speech.googleapis.com --project=<Your project name here>

project_number=$(gcloud projects list --filter=<Your project name here> --format="value(PROJECT_NUMBER)")

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding neos-stt-0 --member serviceAccount:service-${project_number?}@gcp-sa-speech.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/speech.serviceAgent
```

The service account you are using must have the following permission

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <project-name-here> --member serviceAccount:<service-account-here> --role roles/speech.editor
```